# Why Char is actually a NumericType in Java, but not a SymbolicType or String?

Tags: java

Regarding Java syntax, there is a `NumericType` which consists of `IntegralType` and `FloatingPointType`. IntegralTypes are `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `char`.

At the same time, I can assign a single character to `char` variable.

```
char c1 = 10;
char c2 = 'c';
```

So here is my question. Why char in numeric type and how JVM convert 'c' to a number?

Comment: Because of the ASCII table (or unicode in Java's case). Every character can be converted into a number, in fact all data is comprised of numbers, it is a programming standard in most languages that chars are implemented as numbers (for example in C and C++ chars are bytes, they don't have a byte type).

The letter 'c' would become 99 in ASCII.

Comment: No, folks, `char`s in Java are not ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why char in numeric type...

Using numbers to represent characters as indexes into a table is the standard way the text is handled in computers. It's called [*character encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) and has a long history, going back at least to telegraphs. For a long time personal computers used ASCII (a 7-bit encoding = 127 characters plus nul) and then "extended ASCII" (an 8-bit encoding of various forms where the "upper" 128 characters had a variety of interpretations), but these are now obsolete and suitable only for niche purposes thanks to their limited character set. Before personal computers, popular ones were EBCDIC and its precursor BCD. Modern systems use [Unicode](http://unicode.org) (usually by storing one or more of its [transformations](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) such as UTF-8 or UTF-16) or various standardized "code pages" such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

> ...and how JVM convert 'c' to a number?

Java's [numeric `char` values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) map to and from characters via Unicode (which is how the JVM knows that `'c'` is the value 0x0063, or that `'é'` is 0x00E9). Specifically, a `char` value maps to a *Unicode code point* and strings are [sequences of code points](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3).

There's quite a lot about the `char` data type, including why the value is 16 bits wide, in the [JavaDoc of the `Character` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html):

> Unicode Character Representations
>
> The `char` data type (and therefore the value that a Character object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode Standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value. (Refer to the definition of the U+n notation in the Unicode Standard.)
>
> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).
>
> A char value, therefore, represents Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) code points, including the surrogate code points, or code units of the UTF-16 encoding. An int value represents all Unicode code points, including supplementary code points. The lower (least significant) 21 bits of int are used to represent Unicode code points and the upper (most significant) 11 bits must be zero. Unless otherwise specified, the behavior with respect to supplementary characters and surrogate char values is as follows:
>
> - The methods that only accept a char value cannot support supplementary characters. They treat char values from the surrogate ranges as undefined characters. For example, Character.isLetter('\uD840') returns false, even though this specific value if followed by any low-surrogate value in a string would represent a letter.
> - The methods that accept an int value support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters. For example, Character.isLetter(0x2F81A) returns true because the code point value represents a letter (a CJK ideograph).
>
> In the Java SE API documentation, Unicode code point is used for character values in the range between U+0000 and U+10FFFF, and Unicode code unit is used for 16-bit char values that are code units of the UTF-16 encoding. For more information on Unicode terminology, refer to the Unicode Glossary.

Comment: This is really a comprehensive explanation with the useful links. However, I still don't understand how it answers the question. For example, using numbers as boolean expressions was also the standard way in programming languages (`0` is `false`, not `0` is `true`). However, you cannot assign an `int` to `boolean` in Java. What would be hurt if `char` were a non-integral type like `boolean` (except of providing better type-safety)? At least the compiler would report the following code as invalid instead of letting it print `b` in runtime: `new StringBuilder('a').append('b').toString()`. :)

Comment: @DraganBozanovic: "Why" language design questions are always tricky, it comes down to "Because that's what the designers did." :-) I ***think*** in this case, the utility of being able to do math on `char` values was considered useful enough that making them numeric had clear value, and that there wasn't clear value in doing math on `boolean` values. But at the end of the day, one would really have to ask James Gosling (or find somewhere he's answered that question in the past). :-)

Comment: My thinking is similar; thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Because underneath Java represents chars as Unicode. There is some convenience to this, for example you can run a loop from 'A' to 'Z' and do something. It's important to realize, however, that in Java Strings aren't strictly arrays of characters like they are in some other languages. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Internally `char` is stored as ASCII (or UNICODE) code which is integer. The difference is in how it is processed after it is read from memory.

In C/C++ `char` and `int` are very close and is type casted implicitly. Similar behavior in Java shows the relation between C/C++ and Java as JVM is written in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Besides being able to do arithmetic operations on chars which sometimes comes handy (like `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'`) I would say it is a design decision driven by the similar approach taken in other languages when Java was invented (primarily C and C++).

The fact that `Character` does not extend `Number` (as other numeric primitive wrappers do) somehow indicates that Java designers tried to find some kind of a compromise between numeric and non-numeric nature of characters.

**DISCLAIMER** I was not able to find any official docs about this.

Comment: Of course, if defining `char` to be a not-really-numeric type specifically for characters, they could have defined `>=` and `<=` and `+` and `-` such that they worked in a `char`-specific way (as with strings and `+`). It just overcomplicates things. :-) Not quite sure what you mean by "later" in terms of `char` vs `Character`, but I don't think `Character` ever extended `Number` (and we've always had the boxing types). Found a [JDK 1.0.2 reference](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.Character.html#_top_) showing that it doesn't. :-) Best I could do.

Comment: True, my fault, I didn't express myself clearly. I edited the answer; thanks for the remark.