# If Java is Strongly typed then why does this code compile?

Tags: java, types, casting, strong-typing, weak-typing

My understanding of strongly typed was that the language wouldn't make implicit type conversions. However, this code converts the char to it's ascii value and then uses that value.

```
static char x = 'j';
static int y = 7;

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(y+x);
}
```

Comment: "Strongly typed" means different things to different people, but there are plenty of implicit conversions in Java. Given that this question relies on the meaning of "strongly typed", I've voted to close it as an opinion-based question.

Comment: A char is just an unsigned 16 bit number. Nothing special here.

Answer (score 3):

This has little to do with strong or weak typing. Your code is an example of an implicit cast between two strongly typed variables - a `char` and `int`.

Your `System.out.println(y+x)` is actually compiled to `System.out.println(y+(int)x);` so `System.out.println(int arg0)` is invoked.

The cast `(int)x` is what converts the character to its ascii value simply because Java stores chars as UTF-16 values.

Answer (score 2):

> If Java is Strongly typed then why does this code compile?

Because the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) says so. In this case we are [widening a primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), a char can turn into an int. And then we can add two ints and output the result. You could then [narrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) the int back into a char if you wanted.

```
System.out.println((char) (y+x));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Java is a strongly typed programming language because every variable must be declared with a data type. A variable cannot start off life without knowing the range of values it can hold, and once it is declared, the data type of the variable cannot change.

Examples:

The following declaration is allowed because the variable has "hasDataType" is declared to be a boolean data type:

```
 boolean hasDataType;
```

For the rest of its life, hasDataType can only ever have a value of true or false.

And why char was converted in numeric in you example.

```
System.out.println(y+x);
```

You can take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050815/why-char-is-actually-a-numerictype-in-java-but-not-a-symbolictype-or-string)

Comment: What you are defining here is static vs dynamic typing. Op is correctly referring to weak vs strong typing. You are answering something completely different to what he/she is asking